# Problem with Session State in Internet Explorer!

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, session

I have a website to which i've added dynamic javascript code generated on server. Code generated is an image file with some guids as query strings. I use Handler to create js response while at the same i assign Session unique value for new visitor so i can distinguish those from already surfing on site user. All browsers save Session during postbacks on initial site except Internet Explorer which generates each time new Guid for already existing customer.

Is there any way to fix it? Why does this happen?

Comment: I am pretty sure you cannot assign a value to the Session property. It is read-only. What kind of session are you talking about and how exactly do you assign this value?

Comment: ASP.NET Session, it is not read-only

Comment: eugeneK the properties in the Page object and HttpContext.Current are both read only. Where can you set the Session?

Comment: I want to add value to Session collection.

Comment: Oh I see. For some reason I thought you were creating custom session implementation.

Comment: I hope it wouldn't be ever needed. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end with help from @CResults and @Alex Key i've found out that IE blocks 3rd party cookies by default which was a case in my project.

Fix was as simple as adding p3p HTTP Header to Handler...

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("p3p", "CP=\"IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\"");
```

thanks to both of ya!!!

Answer (score 6):

Does any of part of your URL contain underscores?  I've seen this cause problems with IE and session state before, especially when the same code works fine in other browsers.

**Addition**

As per your comment below your URL (most likely the hostname) contains an underscore. ALthough  all the other browsers you are using cope OK with this, IE doesn't - however, in its defence (and I don't usually defend IE) an underscore is an illegal character in a DNS hostname.

I'm guessing you are accessing a local machine which has a NETBIOS name that includes an underscore, such as OFFICEPC_12.

As a workaround you could try

1. Replace the name of the server with its IP address e.g http://192.168.0.55/mypage.aspx
2. Add an entry into your HOSTS file with an alias for this pc, the alias not having underscores
3. Best solution really, change the name of the server!

Comment: yep,,, it does. Is there anyway to avoid it? Maybe URIEncode in Javascript?

Comment: See my edits above. URLEncoding probably won't work. Best solution is to remove the underscore at source.

Comment: Good answer @CResults I came across this problem the other day, was pulling my hair out! It's part of the security of IE not to set / share cookie on domains it believes are invalid.                             A useful link: Internet Explorer Cookie Internals (FAQ): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/08/20/wininet-ie-cookie-internals-faq.aspx

Comment: Actually @Alex Key's link helped me to understand more this issue. IE doesn't allow 3rd party cookies by default. This is the issue and no non letters in my URI.

Comment: @CResults, removed uderscore. Same problem happens. Seems it is not there.