# HttpContext.Current.Session is null in ASP.NET application when accessed in Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Working:

ASP.NET Application is hosted on IIS 8.5.

In bindings we have provided the domain name to the website.

When we try to access the website with domain name then the HttpContext.Current.Seesion throws null reference exception on Internet Explorer any version.

But the same application works fine on Chrome and Firefox.

Also it works fine in Internet Explorer without domain name i.e. with IP.

Setting the **sessionstate** property **cookieless** to **AutoDetect or true**   web.config in fixes the issue, but the cookie with some ID is visible in URL which we want to avoid.

Can anyone please help if we are missing with any setting on IIS or another way.

Comment: Is Internet Explorer configured to allow cookies?

Comment: I think this post may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855784/problem-with-session-state-in-internet-explorer

Comment: @Mason we have allowed cookies.

Comment: @Aderbal thanks for the reply its with the underscores in URL. Removing the underscore from URL fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Solution Found:

Removing the underscores in the URL name i.e. in DNS name.

Refer link: 
[Problem with Session State in Internet Explorer!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855784/problem-with-session-state-in-internet-explorer)